# How to handle desktop vs mobile layout for a component when the mobile design is VERY different (aka cannot make use of grid layout)?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, mobile

I'm building a react application and using bootstrap.  Unfortunately, one of my pages features a google map + list on desktop, but on mobile I want to show EITHER the map or the list (using a toggle).

On desktop, the map takes up about 75% of the container width, and the list takes up the remaining 25%.

My solution right now involves using three classes - `desktop`, `mobile-list` (shows only the list), and `mobile-map` (shows only the map).  I use `display: none` on the `desktop` class when its mobile view.

On the mobile breakpoints, the view changes based on the current state in my reducer based on whether the user has toggled list or not.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  I'm worried that if the styles fail for some reason its going to look awful.

Comment: You could accomplish this through JS too, but in the end, if your styles fail for some reason, everything is going to look awful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function and changed layout based on width like -

```
generateTemplate: function(){
        if( mobile ) {

            return (
                <div className="media">
                    Hello Mobile
                </div>
            );
        } else {

         return (
                <div className="media">
                    Hello Desktop
                </div>
            );
      }
    },
```

and in the render use it like -

```
render: function() {

        let template = this.generateTemplate();

        return (
            <div>
                {template}
            </div>
        );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Do you think this is preferable to the CSS solution?

Comment: Yes you can create different layouts for mobile and desktop.

Comment: Also I want to mention that I'm rendering the component on the server (not the map results, of course those happen after its loaded in the client).  I can't determine width on the server, so how can I handle that?

Comment: You can determine width on the client side. Refer to this - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery)

Comment: Thanks.  I think I will have to figure out a way to defer the actual map part, but I will do it using JS.  That way at least I have two failsafe.